# Creating new sets of object arrays from an object with date ranges

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Let say I have a date range that has a specified start and end date. I want to loop through each day, and each loop I will add the date to an empty object(2) and once the length of object(2) has reach a specific length I want to push obj(2) to the main object(1) and continue with the loop.

```
var startDate = new Date('Tue Oct 18 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800');
var endDate = new Date('Tue Nov 16 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800');
var week = [] (object(2))
var weekObj= [] (object(1))
```

So what I did was this,

```
for(var d = startDate; d <= endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        if(week.length === 7) {
          weekObj.push(week)
        } else {
          function removeTime(date) {
            return new Date(
              date.getFullYear(),
              date.getMonth(),
              date.getDate()
            )
          }
          let date = removeTime(d)
          week.push(date)
        }
      }
      console.log(week)
      console.log(week.length)
```

I was expecting a result like this

```
[
 [
    "2022-10-18T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-19T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-20T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-21T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-22T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-23T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-24T16:00:00.000Z"
 ],
 [
    "2022-10-25T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-26T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-27T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-28T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-29T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-30T16:00:00.000Z",
    "2022-10-31T16:00:00.000Z" 
 ]
  .... an so on , until it finishes the loop
```

But instead it, the loop is already breaking after giving the first seven days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var startDate = new Date('Tue Oct 18 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800');
var endDate = new Date('Tue Nov 16 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800');
var week = [];
var weekObj = [];
for (var d = startDate; d <= endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
  if (week.length === 7) {
    weekObj.push(week);
    week = [];
  } else {
    function removeTime(date) {
      return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
    }

    let date = removeTime(d);
    week.push(date);
  }
}
console.log(week);
console.log(week.length);
console.log(weekObj);
```

You missed reinitializing the array `week` after pushing it to `weekObj`.

```js
weekObj.push(week);
week = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the response, it turns out that I can use splice and while loop for this problem.

```
 var weekObj = []
  var weeks = []
  for(var d = startDate; d <= endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    function removeTime(date) {
      return new Date(
        date.getFullYear(),
        date.getMonth(),
        date.getDate()
      )
    }
    let date = removeTime(d)
    weeks.push(date)
  }

  while(weeks.length !== 0) {
    let lastEle = this.state.periodCount
    /* lastEle, is the index of how many should I cut and add to the new 
     object*/
    var arrayEle = weeks.splice(0, lastEle)
    weekObj.push(arrayEle)
  }
```